# How to make concurrent executions in WampServer?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I use WampServer for running some PHP scripts.
However when I run a long-processing script (say `http://localhost/first.php`), and then I try to open a completely independent script (`http://localhost/second.php`), it will not open until the first script finishes its long-running operation.

I've tried setting "max concurrent clients" to 8 in `httpd`, and `session.autostart` disabled in `php.ini` but nothing helped.

Comment: Close the session before running the thing that takes a long time. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close But also anything that takes longer than a few seconds should probably run asynchronously in the background. Pop a job into a queue [eg: RabbitMQ] and have a worker or two waiting in the background [eg: managed by Supervisord] and let those handle the processing while your webserver serves the webs.

Comment: @Sammitch can you convert your comment into answer? i will choose that.